# Xpages tooltips stop showing

Tags: tooltip, xpages

This seems like a strange one....  I have an xpages repeat, within which I'm displaying a grid of images, each in an inputRichText.  Each of the images has a Tooltip (from the extension library) associated with it.  The tooltips work fine up to some point in the grid, but eventually one of the elements "breaks" something, and no more tooltips are displayed from that point on.  Since this is within a repeat, the code is of course identical.  The HTML in the browser shows very different things between the working and broken tooltips, though; for example:

```
<div id="dijit_Tooltip_8" class="dijitTooltipData" lang="en" style="display:none;" dojotype="dijit.Tooltip" connectid="view:_id1:rowRepeat:4:parentPanel" widgetid="dijit_Tooltip_8">
```

which works (and is the last one in the list that does), vs:

```
<div style="display:none;" dojotype="dijit.Tooltip" connectid="view:_id1:rowRepeat:5:parentPanel">
```

which doesn't work.  (parentPanel is an xpages panel that contains the image and a label.  It still fails if I point directly to the inner inputRichText containing the image.)  The latter doesn't have an id or widgetid, which makes me suspicious, but given this is xpages-generated code, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Unfortunately, this code resides on a computer not on the internet, so I can't paste it here....  But can anyone guess what might be happening?

Thanks,
Reid

Comment: You can also get similar functionality by using the "title" attribute.  It will be rendered by your browser as a tooltip when you hover over the field.  Note that it doesn't play too well with the placeholder text.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I might be able to switch to that, but I'm using the more advanced tooltip to display better-formatted text.  It'd be a shame to have to give that up....

Comment: I understand. You can compute that value, but you have no control over the formatting.  I think it is an HTML5 thing designed for accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be caused by something unrelated.  I was using a repeat to generate some convoluted HTML, and there was an error there.  I don't know exactly what was happening, but apparently it broke the HTML enough to block the mouse hover detection in certain areas.  So, the tooltip is fine.